# Cómo liberar/recuperar un "objeto semáforo" después de una terminación forzosa de un proceso?

Tags: c++, windows, semaphore

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con semáforos. Y me ha pasado unas cuantas veces que después de una teminación forzosa del proceso (debido a algún error en el código) luego no puedo volver a usar el objeto semaforo **con ese mismo nombre**. (La única forma que conozco sería reiniciando el PC). Supongo que esto ocurre porque el manejador del semáforo no se cerró al terminar el proceso y luego queda inaccesible.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de recuperar este "objeto semáforo" **con ese mismo nombre** cuando vuleva a ejecutar el proceso (Sin tener que reiniciar el PC).

Esta es mi clase Semaphore:

```
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#include <windows.h>
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#ifndef SEMAPHORE_H
#define SEMAPHORE_H
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
///+------------------------------------------------------------------+
class Semaphore
{
    HANDLE handle;
    const char  *name;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attributes;

    int initialCount;
    int maximumCount;

    LONG lReleaseCount;
    LPLONG lpPreviousCount;

public:
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Semaphore(const char  *pName = "Semaphore")
    {
        name         = pName;
        attributes   = NULL;
        initialCount = 0;
        maximumCount =10000;

        lReleaseCount = 0;
        lpPreviousCount = 0;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~Semaphore()
    {
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Create()
    {
        handle = CreateSemaphore
        (
            attributes,
            initialCount,
            maximumCount,
            name
        );

        if (handle == NULL)  return false;
        return true;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    bool Open(DWORD pDesiredAccess = SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS,  BOOL pInheritHandle = TRUE)
    {
        handle = OpenSemaphore
        (
            pDesiredAccess,
            pInheritHandle,
            name
        );
        if (handle == NULL) return false;
        return true;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Wait(bool pTimeoutReturn=true)
    {
        switch(WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE))
        {
            case WAIT_ABANDONED:
            return false;

            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            return true;

            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:           
            return pTimeoutReturn;

            case WAIT_FAILED:
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Release()
    {
        lpPreviousCount = &lReleaseCount;
        lReleaseCount++;
        return ReleaseSemaphore(handle, lReleaseCount, lpPreviousCount);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Close()
    {
        if (handle != NULL)CloseHandle(handle);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool InitServer()
    {
        if(!Create())return false;
        if(!Open())return false;
        return true;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool InitClient()
    {
        if(!Open())return false;
        return true;
    }
};
   ///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Y este sería mi programa de pruebas:

NOTA: También estoy usando un archivo mapeado en memoria pero eso no me está dando problemas. Creo que no sería necesario adjuntar su clase aquí, pero si ustedes creen que es necesario me lo dicen y la pongo.

```
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "../../../SharedMemory.h"
#include "../../../Semaphore.h"
#include<iostream>
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using namespace std;
///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{

    SharedMemory *sm = new SharedMemory("Local\\OutputData");
    Semaphore *sem = new Semaphore("Semaphore");

    if(!sm->InitServer())
    {
        cout << "Mapeo de Archivo!! Errno: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if(!sem->InitServer())
    {
        std::cout << "Creado de Semaforo!! Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    ///leer la cantidad de datos que se van a obtener
    int limit = 0;
    sem->Wait(true);
    sm->Read( (void*)&limit, sizeof(int));
    cout << "limit -->"<< limit << endl;
    sem->Release();


    ///Leer datos
    char var[256];
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        sem->Wait(true);
        sm->Read( (void*)&var,255 );
        cout<<i <<"->"<<var << endl;
        sem->Release();
    }


    sm->Close();
    sem->Close();
    delete sem;
    delete sm;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas try-catch? En el catch puede liberar lo que requieras. Puedes utilizar catch(...) para cualquier excepción si quieres pero preferible que sean excepciones nombradas.

Comment: Si lo he pensado... pero el problema es que no sé donde se va a producir la proxima excepción... es decir, tal vez tuve un error codificando (Tal vez excedi el tamaño de un array por poner un supuesto) pero eso lo puedo arreglar en cuanto me doy cuenta de que está fallando ahí.... este tipo de cosas me puede pasar infinidad de veces mientras codifico... y cada vez que el programa me explota tengo que cambiarle el monbre al semaforo tanto en el cliente y como en el servidor  para poder usarlo... es eso o reiniciar el equipo...  es una lata!! Gracias por tu respuesta!! Saludos!!

Comment: Es que justamente los try-catch son para capturar excepciones y es una buena practica utilizarlos en aquellas partes donde el proceso pueda dar excepciones. En todo caso, tambien tienes los Assert. El problema del semaforo quizá puedas hacer un OpenSemaphore cuando falle el Create. Si lo abre puedes cerrarlo o seguir.

Comment: Si, lo del OpenSemaphore ya lo habia intentado y no funcionó...  Descubrí que el problema está relacionado con que si el servidor explota y el cliente queda vivo el recurso del semáforo se queda inaccesile para el servidor... la única forma de que el servidor pueda volver a usarlo es matando al cliente también... Puede que tenga algo que ver con que el servidor se ejecuta en windows y el cliente se ejecuta mediante otro programa que hace las veces de sistema operativo... de hecho tengo que cerrar ese otro programa también para que todo vuelva a funcionar... Gracias por tu ayuda!! Saludos!!

Comment: ¿Porque no haces prueba por cada función y  mides la memoria reservada?